# Can Google Sheets pull a number from a table based on a different number

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I'm using google sheets to make calculations for a game I'm playing. I've made a table that shows how many materials are needed to build a building, and which materials I need to make those materials. The problem is that the base materials vary based on how many buildings I've made. The way I go around this is using the sum function. So:
Sum(P38:P42)

It's annoying to have to select the right range every time though. Is there a way for google sheets to calculate which row of the table I need from the number on the left? For instance, in table:

```
1|20
2|20
3|125
4|450
5|625
```

If I just want the sum of 2 to 4, how can I make it so that I just have to enter 2 and 4 in two cells to get the sum of 20+125+450?

Sorry if I worded it in a weird way, all help appreciated.

Comment: The example table obviously needs to be vertical.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&D1&":B"&D2))
```

[image: 0]